# writing a generic function for summing array of numbers in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a function that takes an array of unknown type of numbers(it may be anything ranging from short to long double)
summing them up and returning the sum.
I'm trying to do this without taking in a string that identify the type passed and using switch case.

how would you go around writing a clean and generic such of code?

**EDIT:** for clearity I will add that I'm talking about the c90 standard , and numbers only. and yet I wish it to be as generic as possible

**Another EDIT** there are no restrictions on the number and type of parameters. the only requesition is for the function to be generic.
a possible prototype for the function might be void *sum(void *arr,int arrsize,...)
or what ever.

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: Do you know the types at compile time or at runtime?

Comment: That is interasting how function can take one array of values of different types... the statemant is incorrect in the definition of array

Comment: @FelixGuo How can he know the type at runtime in C?

Comment: @AGNGazer; By asking user about the type.

Comment: well I did it using a switch case. which doesn't seem very elegant nor generic

Comment: @haccks But he wants to avoid passing any kind of type info to that summing function: _"I'm trying to do this without taking in a string that identify the type passed and using switch case."_ So, while he can ask the user anything he wants - he does not want to use that information.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add some example explaining what you really want to do. It is unclear to know your intent with the current wordings of your question.

Comment: the user may pass an array of ints, an array of doubles or short ot whatever he likes. the function should return a pointer to the sum of the numbers in that array. it doesn't get any clearer than that.

Comment: **Why do you ask?** Please **edit your question** to improve it. Smells like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: that is the question, no XY problem here(it is a question that was recieved in an exam that was given today)

Comment: @naor.z It can get clearer.  Code **in C, cannot directly pass an array to a function** - it is converted into the address of of the first element - the array size is lost.  How should the function determine the number of elements in the array? Another parameter, a sentential?

Comment: "how would you go around writing a clean and generic such of code?" I would write a template function. Oh.. oups...

Comment: like you many have tried to write code in C outside of it's scoped. OOP, overloading, polymorphism, etc. Many have failed. Take my advice: use C as C

Comment: @bolov I'll take your advice , but this question is not intended to be practical for an actual project. it was a part of an exam on that was given today.

Comment: for those devoting the question, I find it amazing the inverse proportion between question complexity and rating in stack overflow. the dumber the question is the more votes it get. maybe I should have changed the title to "how to write an if else statement" to fit the view.

Comment: "takes an array of unknown type of numbers" --> are the array elements to contain the same type of number?

Comment: well its an array, it can't be not of the same type

Comment: An array can have elements that are a `union` whose active member types differ.

Comment: well the type is the union type. a complete one otherwise u can not create an array. so technically that doesn't count

Comment: @naor.z Technical true, Yet since the post can be interpreted in various ways, these questions need to be asked as those who makes posts  like this often have a imprecise understanding of C.

Comment: A C90 `generic_add()` needs 3 inputs: the array address, the array size/count, type information (e.g. an `enum`) and a way to report the sum - perhaps via a `union`.  Do these limitations meet the criteria?

Comment: @chux; He already said he do not want user to give info about the type: *"I'm trying to do this without taking in a string that identify the type passed"*.

Comment: well I guess that using a string or a constant integer to identify the type is the only way of doing such a thing. honestly , I'm amazed

Comment: @haccks [Disagree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45358303/writing-a-generic-function-for-summing-array-of-numbers-in-c/45358715?noredirect=1#comment77679984_45358303) as the function make receive type info in other ways than a _string_.

Comment: @chux; [Can't deduce much from the given info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45358303/writing-a-generic-function-for-summing-array-of-numbers-in-c?noredirect=1#comment77678393_45358303).

Comment: @naor.z The lack of doing this without a type identifier is partially solved with C11 (maybe C99) with `_Generic`.  This post is looking for a C90 solution and so precludes that advancement.

Comment: One of the many issues not addressed in the question is 'what is the result type'?  There are limits on how many values you can add before you run into overflows — especially with a type like `short` (less so with a `double`). A less serious issue is 'what does a generic zero look like', or 'what is the starting value for the result'.  You've not specified how big the arrays might be — if they're only in the range of thousands of entries, there are fewer issues than if you need to handle millions, billions or larger sizes of array.

Comment: Well, I guess the cowards' way out would be to pass in the array pointer, the length, item size, a result pointer and a function that takes a couple pointers and adds the pointer targets.  That would work?

Answer (score 4):

You can't write such a function portably because there is no overloading in C, and because various integral types have *different* machine representations, sizes (as given by `sizeof`) and alignment (as given by `alignof`) and different calling conventions (often, `double` argments are passed in specific registers, while integral arguments use general purpose registers).

However you might make it a *macro*.

Look into [`<tgmath.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/tgmath) and [`_Generic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic); they both require a recent version of C (i.e. [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision))). Look also into GCC [`typeof`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) and [`__builtin_types_compatible_p`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins)  (and notice that many GCC extensions are accepted by other compilers).

You could also declare some [*variadic*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic) function (even in C99). You'll then use a discriminating argument (passed to `va_start`) to tell (at runtime) 
your implementation the types of the following arguments.

BTW, you could be interested by the [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) library, and Glib [GVariant](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-GVariant.html) might be inspirational.

Comment: but i'm speaking of a c90 implementation to this. is there no way doing this portably?

Comment: GCC extensions are quite popular (and exist in Clang). You might use them. And a variadic function is portable (perhaps to C90, I leave you to check).

Comment: @naor.z - yes there is. It is called C++.

Answer (score 1):

A generic function to add needs 3 inputs:

1. Data: (as a pointer to its first element of the array)
2. Size: the sizeof the array or better, its element count
3. Type information identifying a finite numbers of types like `short`, `unsigned`, `double`.  C90 does not have `long double`.

And a way to return the result.

```
union gen {
  double d;
  unsigned u;
  short s;
};
```

Some C/pseudo-code

```
// form IDs, one for each type.
// As OP does not want a string, use an enumerated type
enum g_type {
  g_short,
  g_unsigned,
  g_double,
  g_N
};

// form add functions, one for each type.
union gen add_double  (double *data  , size_t count);
union gen add_unsigned(unsigned *data, size_t count);
union gen add_short   (short *data   , size_t count) {
  gen sum.s = 0;
  while (count > 0) { 
    sum.s += data[--count];
  }
  return sum.s;
}

// Master add function
union gen gen_add(void *data, size_t count, enum g_type id) {
  gen (*addf)()[g_N] = { add_short, add_unsigned, add_double };  // function list
  assert(id < g_N);
  return (addf[id])(data, count);
}
```

With C11, `_Generic` can be used to avoid the need for code to explicitly call out the the type ID.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we can pass extra arguments as we like

```
void summary(void *arr, int arr_size, char *type, void *result){
    int i;

    if ( strcmp(type, "int") == 0 ) {
        int *temp = (int *)arr, sum = 0;
        for ( i = 0; i < arr_size; i++ ) {
            sum += temp[i];
        }
        *((int *)result) = sum;
    } else if( strcmp(type, "double") == 0 ) {
        double *temp = (double *)arr, sum = 0;
        for ( i = 0; i < arr_size; i++ ) {
            sum += temp[i];
        }
        *((double *)result) = sum;
    } else if( strcmp(type, "float") == 0 ) {
        float *temp = (float *)arr, sum = 0;
        for ( i = 0; i < arr_size; i++ ) {
            sum += temp[i];
        }
        *((float *)result) = sum;
    } else if ( strcmp(type, "char") == 0 ) {
        char *temp = (char *)arr, sum = 0;
        for ( i = 0; i < arr_size; i++ ) {
            sum += temp[i];
        }
        *((char *)result) = sum;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Please provide a legal numeric type.\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int result;
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    summary(&arr, 4, "int", &result);
    printf("%d\n", result); /* prints 10 */

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the most wide type for all values - e.g. all initial numbers will be represented as `double` values and stored in the array of `double`, so your function will take array of double and make summation.

All type transformation should be outside the summation function if you really want to have one array as input:

```
double sumarr(double * arr, int cnt)
{
     int i;
     double sum = 0;
     for(i =0; i < cnt; i++)
     {
         sum += arr[i];
     }
     return sum;
}
```

Comment: it is a question taken from a test that was given today, they asked not to use double and to write it as generic as possible

Comment: @naor.z Generic? in C? what do you mean? `void * arr`?

Comment: well yea, i know that it's not totally generic. but i may assume it to point to an array of numbers

Comment: @naor.z in C all numbers has type, so if you define array you have to define type, and this type is one for all items in this array

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is when you call the `+` operator, C needs to know what it's adding. As generic as you can get is the size of the input. When you have two integers, let's say, 5 + 6, the bytes look like this when the two elements are stored next to each other, each 4 bytes long:

```
00 00 00 05 00 00 00 06
```

How does C know that you want to add the first 4 bytes to the number at the next 4 bytes? Because you declare it as an `int` type. (In systems where `sizeof(int)` is `4`).

So when you come along with numeric sizes that are different, lets say a `double` which is typically 8 bytes, C needs to know the size of the types you are working with.

The purely C generic way would be to use `void*`, but that does not solve the size issue unless you also pass in the size of one element.